# You are not connected replacement in case Internet Explorer seems disconnected

Tags: internet-explorer-11, placeholder

Is there any way to replace the page that is shown if you are not connected to the internet?

A list with tips about network cables, flight mode, access points, routers and mobile devices is presented if I start IE while being disconnected. This list is in my case not very helpful.

I would like to offer a modified checklist, another as the one that is shown to every user.

And I don't want to do this with a default start page, hosted on a webserver on the same device.

Have not found any information about that in IEAK 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite those pages using the registry: `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\AboutURLs`

You are looking for the `OfflineInformation` entry ([Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Registry_Hacks/Internet_Explorer))

> And I don't want to do this with a default start page, hosted on a webserver on the same device

Just put the html file on the disk and put the filename into the registry key.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/395137/how-to-replace-internet-explorer-error-pages